# How to change an HTTP request to imitate sending from US?

Tags: java, cookies, http-headers

I am repeating the airbnb request by Java applicaiton using Apache HTTP Components while being outside of the US.    In Chrome and Mozilla I am getting the price in dollars, in my Java application in the local currency.  Also, I am getting the local currency price in Safari that was not used for airbnb before.  So, the difference is in cookies, correct?

However, when I see the cookies in  Chrome I do not see the cookie that is responsible for location. There is a list of 45 cookies, should I add to HTTP request all of them?  Is there any other way to get prices in dollars?

There is no currency in this list of 45 cookies, still I tried to add the currency

```
      BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
      BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("currency", "USD");
      cookie.setDomain(".airbnb.com");
      cookie.setPath("/");
      cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

      HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();
```

This did not help.  Would it be possible to add cookies from the Chrome cookies directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it is Cookies. You are wrong it's not location. There is a currency header as can be seen:
[image]

This is also how it is set during a GET method:

[image]

Comment: There is also _user_attributes header in cookies which indicates the currency as:

_user_attributes=%7B%22curr%22%3A%22USD%22%2C.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the **browser's** language appears as `accept-language` in HTTP request headers. For my knowledge, there are no cookies indicating the origin country of the request or the currency **in all browsers and in all HTTP request** (I think Chrome has one, but it's unreliable).

If this header key is not there, alternatively, you can check `http-accept-language` in the request header (it depends on the parser you are using).

[image]